# C++ alignment structures

Tags: c++

Its open season on #defines and other macros and I was looking at a portable way of aligning structures 32 bit and 64 bit code. Previously the code had a #define AMD64 and padding was added when this was not the case.

Is this a portable way of doing the same, minus the #if !defined(...) ... #endif

```
constexpr size_t defaultAlignmentBits = 4u;
constexpr size_t defaultAlignmentBytes = 16u;

template<size_t padLen>
struct PadIfNonZero {
    uint8_t pad[padLen];
};
template<>
    struct PadIfNonZero<0> {
};

template<typename T>
using PadToAlignment = PadIfNonZero<(sizeof(T) % defaultAlignmentBytes == 0 ? 0  : defaultAlignmentBytes - sizeof(T) % defaultAlignmentBytes)>;
```

And how can this be improved?

Comment: Have you look at `alignas` ?

Comment: Still not full compiler support for that.  From memory, I had to avoid using it in MSVC++2013, despite C++11 support.  But yeah, moving forward, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your classes and structs to have a certain alignment in memory you should look into the alignas operator. It works like this:

```
Class Foo
alignas(64)
{
     Foo();
     ~Foo();
};
```

Here the class Foo is aligned to 64 bytes. But note that alignas is only available in c++11 or above. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. Much much nicer. However, it only seems to work in the definition and not declaration: ie. Foo bar alignas(64);  I am also guessing that this will only work at compile time too, as there is no directive to align at the new call?

Comment: Right, the alignas only works at compile time. I'm glad it's what you were looking for.